# Apache2, ServerAlias not working

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I know it is a question asked several times, but I've read them all and not solved the problem.

I have configured the virtualhost apache like this:

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.loc`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.loc
ServerAlias www.example.loc

DocumentRoot /var/www/example/web
<Directory /var/www/example/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
```

I put this in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   example.loc
```

and then I loaded the site in this way:

```
sudo a2ensite example.loc
```

and restarted apache.

If I go to `example.loc`, it works properly, but if I go to `www.example.loc`, it does not work, saying that it is "impossible to find `www.example.loc`"!

Have I done something wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entries to `/etc/hosts` are not "inclusive", so your addition of `example.loc` does not include `www.example.loc` (or any other subdomain) as well. So, your browser tries to find `www.example.loc` the usual way, which is by asking the name server(s) you have configured. But of course no nameserver knows anything about this domain. Your local Apache never gets into action this way ;)

As an additional remark, adding names to `/etc/hosts` this way might bring problems in another regard as well. The line `127.0.0.1 example.loc` will probably override the line `127.0.0.1 localhost`, so you might get problems resolving `localhost`. You can assign several names to an ip in one line, so the proper way would be

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.loc www.example.loc
```

Comment: nice! ...I was facing the same issue for last couple of hours! :)